IOS SDK Updated - However META Developers platform doesn't recognize the update
We have updated since February 2024, the META SDKs for both Android & IOS, however META Developers platform doesn't recognize the updated IOS Version, while for Android looks updated.
From META developers platform -> App Settings -> Advanced, we see that the IOS SDK version is stack on V6.5.2 while we have updated the IOS SDK to version to V16.3.1.
What could be the issue? How can we check, apart from META developers platform, that the SDK is updated and recognized by the platform as expected?
We cross checked that the IOS SDK is updated correctly on the App.
